# What are shadow samplers in OpenGL and what are possible uses for them?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shadow

I have been working with [this ES extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shadow_samplers.txt) for a while, but I still don't quite get what these shadows samplers are and what one could use them for. Googling didn't really get me any nice, readable results, so I am posting here.

I am looking for something that would help me to really grok what these could do. This can be either real-life use case or something that would just show how these are different from normal samplers. I mean, okey, they store depth data. But how is that data generated? Is it just made from a texture bound to a depth attachment?

Also, my question applies to both DT (desktop) GL and ES, and possibly to WebGL too; I don't really care about the exact calls or enumerations, since they are easily found in specs.

Comment: Determining whether a fragment is in shadow involves reading a value from a depth texture and comparing that to the fragment's distance in light space. If the former is greater, it's in shadow, otherwise it's lit. You can do this manually, or with a special sampler that does the fetch and compare steps in one. It is not uncommon for a shadow sampler to offer percentage closer filtering "for free", too. That is, read 4 texels instead of 1, compare all 4, and return a single number that describes how many of these tests failed. This allows for somewhat smoother shadow borders.

Comment: @Damon why isn't that an answer? :)

Comment: Mostly because it's not elaborate enough and because I don't have much experience with GL ES (which the question is mainly about). I'd have to dig through the spec of that particular extension first to give a fully qualified answer (and to be sure that this ES extension doesn't behave grossly different from what I expect, as in desktop GL). Though my comment might give you (who has already thoroughly read that spec) enough of a hint to understand what it's about.

Comment: @Damon It's not mainly about ES, look closer; I am asking about a concept rather than ES version in particular. I am also pretty sure that DT version would translate well to ES usage

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A ["shadow sampler"](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Shadow_samplers) is a sampler that is used for [depth comparison textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Comparison_mode). Normally, if you access a depth texture, you get the (filtered) depth value at that texture coordinate. With depth comparison mode however, what you're doing is a different operation.

For each sample fetched from the texture, you compare the depth with a given value. If the comparison passes, then the sample fetched is effectively 1.0. If the comparison fails, it is 0.0. Filtering then works on the samples *after* this comparison. So if I'm doing linear filtering, and half the samples pass the compare and half don't, the value I get is 0.5.

To do this, you must both activate depth comparison on the sampler object/texture object you're using, but you *also* must use a shadow sampler in the shader. The reason for this is that the texture accessing function now needs to take an extra value: the value to compare the texture access against.

This is primarily used for [shadow maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping), hence the name. Shadow maps store the depth from the light to the nearest surface. Therefore, you compare it to the depth from the light to the surface being rendered. If the surface being rendered is closer to the light than what's in the shadow map, then you get 1.0 from the shadow sampler. If the surface is farther from the light, you get 0.0. In either case, you multiply the value by the light color, then do all your lighting computations for that light as normal.

The reason for the comparison before the sampling is something called "Percentage Closer Filtering". Filtering between the depth values doesn't produce reasonable results; it's not what you want. You want to do the comparison first, then filter the compared boolean results. What you then get is a measurement of how many samples from the depth texture passed the comparison. This gives better results along the edges of shadows.

Comment: Damn it's complicated. Thanks a lot for your answer though, after 3rd read I am starting to get it :)